# netbeans - remove subversion binding on mac os x

Tags: svn, macos, netbeans, binding

Im desperately trying to remove subversion bindings in my netbeans project but I cant work out how to. 
I've tried to copy the files to another directory but the original svn bindings stays intact from the original source. Its hopelessly annoying!

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal type `cd /path/to/your/project/` and then `find . -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;`

It should remove the binding.

Comment: Im getting: find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"

Comment: Im pretty sure all .svn files are gone. But Netbeans still keeps the binding... very strange!